# TCP server in Webassembly (C++) fails with accept()

Tags: javascript, c++, sockets, tcp, webassembly

I wrote a simple TCP server-client native application in C. It works as expected (Linux Fedora as well as Cygwin for Windows 10). When I compiled it using EM++ (or EMCC), it built the JS & WASM fine.

$ em++ TcpService.cpp -o TcpService.js -s ASYNCIFY=1

However, while running the server, I see the following error; though it is stuck waiting for arrival of client-data, it never really connects:

$ node TcpService.js

Waiting for arrival of messages ...

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'stream' of undefined**

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'stream' of undefined**

...

I narrowed down the problem to the accept(3) call. Note that previously, I would see a stacktrace (not very useful), in addition to the above TypeError. Now that I am compiling the code with **"-s ASYNCIFY=1"**, the stack trace is gone. However, the client program still doesn't connect (neither native build nor its WASM).

The server program uses simple BSD sockets:

```
void server(void)
{
  // port to start the server on
  int SERVER_PORT = 8877;

  // socket address used for the server
  struct sockaddr_in _ServerAddr;
  memset(&_ServerAddr, 0, sizeof(_ServerAddr));
  _ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

  // htons: host to network short: transforms a value in host byte
  // ordering format to a short value in network byte ordering format
  _ServerAddr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

  // htonl: host to network long: same as htons but to long
  _ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

  // create a TCP socket, creation returns -1 on failure
  int listen_sock;
  if ((listen_sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    throw std::runtime_error("could not create listen socket\n");
  }

  // bind it to listen to the incoming connections on the created server
  // address, will return -1 on error
  if ((bind(listen_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&_ServerAddr,
            sizeof(_ServerAddr))) < 0) {
    throw std::runtime_error("could not bind socket\n");
  }

  int wait_size = 16;  // maximum number of waiting clients, after which
                       // dropping begins
  if (listen(listen_sock, wait_size) < 0) {
    throw std::runtime_error("could not open socket for listening\n");
  }

  // socket address used to store client address
  struct sockaddr_in client_address;
  int client_address_len = 0;

  // run indefinitely
  while (true) {

    // open a new socket to transmit data per connection
    int sock;
    printf("Waiting for arrival of messages ...\n");
    if ((sock =
             accept(listen_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_address,
                    (socklen_t *)&client_address_len)) < 0) {
      throw std::runtime_error("could not open a socket to accept data\n");
    }
    int n = 0;
    int len = 0, maxlen = 100;
    char buffer[maxlen];
    char *pbuffer = buffer;

    printf("client connected with ip address: %s\n",
           inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr));

    // keep running as long as the client keeps the connection open
    while ((n = recv(sock, pbuffer, maxlen, 0)) > 0) {
      pbuffer += n;
      maxlen -= n;
      len += n;

      printf("received: '%s'\n", buffer);

      // echo received content back
      send(sock, buffer, len, 0);
    }

    close(sock);
  }

  close(listen_sock);
}
```

The client is equally simple:

```
void sendMessage(void)
{
  memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));
  server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;

  inet_pton(AF_INET, server_name, &server_address.sin_addr);

  server_address.sin_port = htons(server_port);
  if ((_Sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    printf("could not create socket\n");
  }

  if (connect(_Sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address,
             sizeof(server_address)) < 0) {
    printf("could not connect to server\n");
    return;
  }
  const char* data_to_send = "test message";
  send(_Sock, data_to_send, strlen(data_to_send), 0);
}
```

Googling for the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'stream' of undefined" did NOT prove very useful, especially WRT the stream property - most pages are only relevant to AWS, whereas mine is a simple, local test-program.

I also installed the required websockets NPMs before I could get node to run the application.

Comment: this is very exciting project! Have you succeeded in making it work?

Answer (score 1):

If you have existing TCP networking code written in C/C++ that utilizes the Posix Sockets API, by default Emscripten attempts to emulate such connections to take place over the WebSocket protocol instead. For this to work, you will need to use something like WebSockify on the server side to enable the TCP server stack to receive incoming WebSocket connections. This emulation is not very complete at the moment, it is likely that you will run into problems out of the box and need to adapt the code to work within the limitations that this emulation provides.

This is the default build mode for POSIX sockets, no linker flags or option settings are needed to enable it.

## Full POSIX Sockets over WebSocket Proxy Server

Emscripten provides a native POSIX Sockets proxy server program, located in directory tools/websocket_to_posix_proxy/, that allows full POSIX Sockets API access from a web browser. This support works by proxying all POSIX Sockets API calls from the browser to the Emscripten POSIX Sockets proxy server (via transparent use of WebSockets API), and the proxy server then performs the native TCP/UDP calls on behalf of the page. This allows a web browser page to run full TCP & UDP connections, act as a server to accept incoming connections, and perform host name lookups and reverse lookups. Because all API calls are individually proxied, this support can be slow. This support is mostly useful for developing testing infrastructure and debugging.

The following POSIX sockets functions are proxied in this manner:
socket(), socketpair(), shutdown(), bind(), connect(), listen(), accept(), getsockname(), getpeername(), send(), recv(), sendto(), recvfrom(), sendmsg(), recvmsg(), getsockopt(), setsockopt(), getaddrinfo(), `getnameinfo().
The following POSIX sockets functions are currently not proxied (and will not work):
poll(), close() (use shutdown() instead), select()
To use POSIX sockets proxying, link the application with flags “-lwebsocket.js -s PROXY_POSIX_SOCKETS=1 -s USE_PTHREADS=1 -s PROXY_TO_PTHREAD=1”. That is, POSIX sockets proxying builds on top of the Emscripten WebSockets library, and requires multithreading and proxying the application main() to a pthread.

For an example of how the POSIX Sockets proxy server works in an Emscripten client program, see the file tests/websocket/tcp_echo_client.cpp.

https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/networking.html

Comment: That doesn't make sense? -  `accept()` should not fail, since WebSocket is base on TCP, and thus the TCP connection should be accepted?